# Typescript compile ordering issue gulp-typescript, tsc 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.6

I am using gulp-typescript:"2.9.0" and typescript: "1.6.2" in a Visual Studio 2015 project to compile a folder of angular typescript files into a single app.js file.  The problem i'm having is that concatenated output order isn't correct causing angular to throw exceptions.  Initially I was able to change the alphabetical order of the file names and I could get the correct order but that just stopped working.  I have also tried including all of the files in the correct order in a "_references.ts" file but that doesn't seem to work. I included the _references.ts file that i am using below.  The file 'app.config.ts' always appears at the top of the output and it depends on the 'app.module.ts' file. Does anyone have a solution for this?

```
/// <reference path="../typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/angularjs/angular-route.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="app.module.ts" />
/// <reference path="app.zconfig.ts" />
/// <reference path="app/framework/framework.module.ts" />
/// <reference path="app/framework/psframework.directive.ts" />
/// <reference path="app/framework/menu/menu.module.ts" />
/// <reference path="app/framework/menu/menu.directive.ts" />
/// <reference path="app/framework/menu/menu-item.directive.ts" />
/// <reference path="app/framework/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this using the gulp-angular-filesort plugin. This is the typescript compilation task that made it:

```
gulp.task('compile', function () {
    var pathsArray = paths.js.typescriptDefinitionFile.concat(paths.js.src);

    gulp.src(pathsArray)
        .pipe(typescript({
            target: 'es5',
            noImplicitAny: true,
            preserveConstEnums: true
        }))
        .pipe(angularFilesort())
        .pipe(concat(paths.js.srcOutputFile))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.js.outputFolder));
});
```

I did not use the out option in the typescript configuration object to get a .js file for each .ts file. Then, after using the angular sort plugin, I concat them  separately.

Answer (score 0):

Use sortOutput parameter - set it to true
like here

```
var tscResult = srcResult
        .pipe(gulpTypeScript({
            typescript: require('typescript'),
            sortOutput: true,
            target: "ES5",
            declarationFiles: true,
            noEmitOnError: dontEmitTSbuildErrors,
            out: "./obj/" + outFileName + ".js"
        }, undefined, gulpTypeScript.reporter.longReporter()));
```

Comment: Sort output didn't work for me.  It would still concat the files out of the order specified in the _references file.   I ended up having to explicitly list every file in order in the files collection of the tsconfig.json file.  The issue was that an angular module was declared in one file and then used in another.  Typescript doesn't understand this order therefore I needed to define it.  I have moved to external modules all together.